# shopping cart using Lift

Tags: web-applications, scala, lift

I'm new in Scala programming and Lift framework. I would like to develop a shopping cart in Lift. Do you know some links with examples for this kind of applications? There are many examples for the ASP.NET but I can't find something in Lift.

Comment: @Daniel - agreed.  https://github.com/timperrett/lift-in-action for some coding goodies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Simply Lift](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-6.3.html) has a section about Cells that happens to do a full-blown shopping cart as its example. Mind you, I haven't tried it out myself, but this should be a good place to start.

As an aside,
Simply Lift is written by David Pollak, the creator of Lift. I've been trying to learn Lift as well, and I find that book to be very helpful, but the examples tend to be a bit over the top. I've found [Exploring Lift](http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index.html) to be pretty helpful as well, but the examples are a bit easier to wrap your head around.